# Identify provider, identity management, authorization server

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, identitymanager, identity-provider

I am baffled while understanding OAuth 2.0, OpenID connect and other mechanisms for securing API's. I did online search, but results are varying with contradicting info.

==> Authentication server.

==> Authorization server.

==> Identity provider (IDP).

==> Identity server.

==> Identity manager

who stores userid / password, is it stored in Identity provider, if so, is there any open source identity provider "server" which we can install on local laptop?

who does issue ID token once a user is authenticated, same about access token, who issue access token.

I see some video tutorials, but no one tells which part of the system actually does these tasks. Can anyone help understand?

Comment: The identify provider typically authenticates, often with a password. There are several open source oauth2 servers, see here: https://oauth.net/code/ ( I wrote the second in this list). The oauth2 servers in this list typically issue the access token, and also the id token if they support it. Note that many use-cases don't require id tokens or OpenID Connect, so if your use-case is simpler you don't need that extra overhead.

Comment: Thanks Evert for your response.  who stores the userid/ password, is it Authorization server or Identity server/manager. Could you elaborate your answer, please.

Comment: Usually authorization server and identity server are the same thing